# How do I run code in a standalone Elixir module (outside of a mix app)?

Tags: module, elixir

I am super new to elixir and basically don't really know what I'm doing, anyway I have the following code

```
defmodule Maze do
 def room do
  correct = "c"
  response = IO.gets("You are in a room with a door, continue? (hit C)");
  if response == correct do
   IO.puts("you continue");
  else 
   IO.puts("you dont continue");
  end
 end
def repeat(x) do
 IO.puts(x)
end 
end
```

But when I go into `iex` and type `Maze.repeat(4)` I get the following error:

```
iex(1)> Maze.repeat(4)
** (UndefinedFunctionError) function Maze.repeat/1 is undefined (module Maze is not available)
    Maze.repeat(4)
```

any suggestions?

Comment: Is this in a mix project or do you have just a single `maze.ex(s)` file?

Comment: @zwippie just maze.ex

Comment: @zwippie but the name of the file is called main.ex if that makes a difference

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `c` function in the iex shell to compile and load the module:

```
c "./main.ex"
```

Answer (score 0):

You've to load the module into **iex** console which can be achieved through below.

```
$ iex
Erlang/OTP 22 [erts-10.5.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [ds:8:8:10] [async-threads:1] [hipe]

Interactive Elixir (1.7.2) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)
iex(1)> c "<realpath to maze.ex file>"
[Maze]
iex(2)> Maze.repeat(1)
1
:ok
```

Answer (score 0):

Passing the `.ex` file as an argument when running iex shell works too.

```
defmodule Maze do
  def random, do: Enum.random(1..1000)
end
```

```sh
$ iex test.ex
Erlang/OTP 22 [erts-10.4] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:1] [hipe]

Interactive Elixir (1.10.2) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)
iex(1)> Maze.random
866
iex(2)> Maze.random
520
iex(3)>
```